# How can I prevent a user inputting the same username or userID as another user?

Tags: python, mysql, primary-key

I have made a registering system which takes in the information of a user and stores that within a database. I have made the userID and username a primary key, how can I alter my code so that a user can not register with the same user name or userID.

```
def register_user():
userid_info = userid.get()
username_info = username.get()
password_info = password.get()
name_info = name.get()
phonenumber_info = phonenumber.get()
email_info = email.get()
region_info = region.get()
accesslevel_info = accesslevel.get()
# Sql code for writing the data that was written in the regsitering page. 
cursor = cnn.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO `users`(`userID`, `userName`, `userPassword`, `name`, `phoneNum`, `email`, `region`, `accessLevel`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
query_vals = (userid_info, username_info, name_info, password_info, phonenumber_info, email_info, region_info, accesslevel_info)
cursor.execute(query, query_vals)
cnn.commit()
cursor.close()
cnn.close()
# removes the values in the entrys once the user selects that the registration was successful
userid_entry.delete(0, END)
username_entry.delete(0, END)
password_entry.delete(0, END)
name_entry.delete(0, END)
phonenumber_entry.delete(0, END)
email_entry.delete(0, END)
region_entry.delete(0, END)
accesslevel_entry.delete(0, END)
Label(screen1, text = "Registration successful", fg = "green", font = ("calibri", 11)).pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the database so that the primary key is just the `userID` and then make the `userName` column a unique key. In that way you cannot have either a duplicate `userId` column nor a duplicate `userName` column. As you had it, it is only the `userId-userName` combination that had to be unique. Then modify your code to handle a possible duplicate key exception (for example: **IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'")**) on the `cursor.execute` statement. If you do get an exception, you can then query the database to determine which column or columns were duplicated if it is not clear from the exception message.

You have to first ensure that your current table has unique `userId` and `userName` columns. For example,

```
select count(distinct userId), count(distinct userName), count(*) from users;
```

The three numbers should all be the same.  If not, you can find the problematic entries with, for example:

```
select count(userId) as cnt, userId
group by userId
having cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search in your database when the new registration occurs if there is a user with same username. Just select from your database where username is equal to new registrations username.

Comment: This  will work for a single user system, but otherwise there is a risk of a race condition where another user creates a record with desired username in between your select and insert.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a list which stores all the ids n passwords and the program check the list for concorent names everytime someone enters a new id

Comment: The database table is essentially such a list already.

Answer (score 0):

since you have already made userID and username as primary keys you can use exception to implement your logic to warn the user.

**edit**: please have only one primary key in your db relation as suggested by another answer.

```
try:
    cursor.execute(query)
except IntegrityError:
    # handle your exception here
    return
```

or using MySQLdb error

```
try:
    cursor.execute(query)
except MySQLdb.Error as e:
# handle your exception here
    return
```

you should use `with` to handle database transactions, `with` handles closing of connections etc even if an exception occurs.

Comment: There is only **one** primary key in a relation and in this case its the combined columns userID and userName. So it's the concatenation of those two columns that must be unique, but not either one separately. So this is not a solution. See my answer (but do not copy).

Comment: My answer was more focused on code to handle the primary key violation. yes, you're right there can only be one primary key in a relation ikr. my answer heading line could be misleading, so editing it with your suggestions.